# Is Compose's swipe-to-dismiss state always remember the old item based on id, even the list has been refresh to newer one?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-swipe-to-dismiss

I have a simple example app that can

- Load a new list (of 2 items, with id 0 and 1, and random text for each)
- It can swipe to dismiss any item.

If I

- load the new list for the first time
- swipe to delete the first item
- load a new list (that has same ID, but different random text)
- swipe to delete the second item

It will crash as shown in the GIF below
(You can get the code design from here https://github.com/elye/issue_android_jetpack_compose_swipe_to_dismiss_different_data_same_id)

[image]

The reason is crashes because, upon Swipe-to-Dismiss the 2 item (of the 2nd time loaded data), the item it found is still the 2 item of the 1st time loaded data.

It does seems dismissState (as shown code below) always remember the 1st time loaded data (instead of the new data loaded)

```
                val dismissState = rememberDismissState(
                    confirmStateChange = {
                        Log.d("Track", "$item\n${myListState.value.toMutableList()}")
                        viewModel.removeItem(item)
                        true
                    }
                )
```

Hence this causes the deletion to send the wrong item in for deletion, and thus causes the failure and crash.

The complete LazyColumn and SwipeToDismiss code is as below

```
       LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
            items(
                items = myListState.value,
                key = { todoItem -> todoItem.id }
            ) { item ->
                val dismissState = rememberDismissState(
                    confirmStateChange = {
                        viewModel.removeItem(item)
                        true
                    }
                )

                SwipeToDismiss(
                    state = dismissState,
                    background = {
                        dismissState.dismissDirection ?: return@SwipeToDismiss
                        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.Red))
                    },
                    dismissContent = {
                        // The row view of each item
                    }
                )
            }
        }
```

Is this

1. My issue, is that I miss out on anything to refresh the dismissState upon loading of new data?
2. A Google Bug, where SwipeToDismiss will always have to work with a list of Unique IDs . Even if the list is refreshed to a new list, it cannot have the same ID that colide with any item of the previous list

   - i.e. if I replace `key = { todoItem -> todoItem.id }` with  `key = { todoItem -> todoItem.title }`, then it will all be good

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rememberDismissState()` will remember the `confirmStateChange` lambda, which is part of the `DismissState`. In your case, `item` can change, but the lambda only captures the initial `item` value, leading to the crash.

You can use `rememberUpdatedState` to solve this:

```
val currentItem by rememberUpdatedState(item)
val dismissState = rememberDismissState(
    confirmStateChange = {
        viewModel.removeItem(currentItem)
        true
    }
)
```